# Send notification email in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

When send the notification email to customer, how to get the password of customer info?
I wanna send the notification email with Password info.

Thanks for your helpness.

Answer (score 0):

When you give access to your customer and check the field "SEND NOTIFICATION EMAIL" under Access tab, due to security reasons NetSuite does not include password information in notification email.

If you wants to include password info in notification email, you will need a custom script - after submit user event script deployed on customer record with criteria of your interest to send notification email. You should also consider not to check SEND NOTIFICATION EMAIL" field.